# How to delimit string based on regular expression using Python

Tags: python, regex, split

I have Python string with below mention data.

```
--- Data-['tag']-['cli'] command ---> show date:

Current time: 2020-03-12 11:36:37 PDT

--- Data-['tag']-['shell'] command ---> show version:

OS Kernel 64-bit  
[builder_stable]

--- Data-['tag']-['cli'] command ---> show host:

Model: New
```

I want to delimit above string based on any line that starts with "--- Data" and ends with ":" irrespective of any contents that is inside between "--- Data" and ":" character.

My python code is shown below.

```
array = data.split("--- Data")

for word in array:
    print(word)
```

I want delimited data to be returned in order and with the delimiter as well.

For e.g. 
First split result should be like:

```
--- Data-['tag']-['cli'] command ---> show date:

Current time: 2020-03-12 11:36:37 PDT
```

Second split result be like:

```
--- Data-['tag']-['shell'] command ---> show version:

OS Kernel 64-bit  
[builder_stable]
```

And so on. Any help?

Comment: use `re.split()` to split using a regex: `import re; re.split('\d+', 'foo1bar23baz456qux')` would return `['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'qux']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `re.findall` with a pattern that looks for the delimiter pattern and then lazily matches any characters until the next delimiter pattern or the end of the string:

```
import re

s = '''--- Data-['tag']-['cli'] command ---> show date:

Current time: 2020-03-12 11:36:37 PDT

--- Data-['tag']-['shell'] command ---> show version:

OS Kernel 64-bit  
[builder_stable]

--- Data-['tag']-['cli'] command ---> show host:

Model: New'''

delimiter = r'--- Data[^\n]*?:'
print(re.findall(r'{0}.*?(?={0}|$)'.format(delimiter), s, re.S))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
import re

s = '''--- Data-['tag']-['cli'] command ---> show date:

Current time: 2020-03-12 11:36:37 PDT

--- Data-['tag']-['shell'] command ---> show version:

OS Kernel 64-bit  
[builder_stable]

--- Data-['tag']-['cli'] command ---> show host:

Model: New'''

split_start = "--- Data"
l = re.split(split_start, s)
curr_split = [split_start+cs for cs in l if cs != ""]
```